# conditionally apply css to th and td's under ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to vertically display all the header texts except the first one.My table is dynamically created using ng-repeat.I tried using ng-class

```
<th class="scenarioTableHeader alignVerticalText" ng-repeat="column in cols"><div class="verticalTextScenario" ng-class="{'scenarioBranchHeader':$first}">{{column}}</div></th>
```

but the default class(verticalTextScenario) overrides the css in ng-class(scenarioBranchHeader)...

I have attached an example in jsfiddle..Any help will be appreciated.https://jsfiddle.net/oeq53xLe/14/

Comment: Just add `-webkit-transform: initial` to your `scenarioBranchHeader` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your div with this :

```
<div ng-class="{'scenarioBranchHeader':$first,'verticalTextScenario':!$first}">{{column}}</div>
```

Updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oeq53xLe/16/)

Comment: This is a better solution. @Ezhil you should accept this answer.

Comment: thanks a bunch @MohammedAzhar tht's exactly what i need...@BramVanroy yes you are right..this answer is more angular oriented anyhow thanks for letting me know how to do it via css

Answer (score 1):

Just change your **scenarioBranchHeader** class to

```
.scenarioBranchHeader{
    text-align: center; 
    width:250px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
}
```

It should do the work. I have added a new fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y1dym7d1/). Just check it out.

Comment: I did try that(forget to include those lines in jsfiidle) but for some reason webkit-transform in verticalTextScenario overrides the webkit-transform in scenarioBranchHeader in my project.But it looks ok in fiddle..guess some other css in my project is causing the problem...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the first child from your CSS selector: https://jsfiddle.net/oeq53xLe/15/

```
th:not(:first-child) .verticalTextScenario {
    ...
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

}
```

Note: don't forget to add the none prefixed properties!! For isntance, Internet Explorer won't work with your code. Add `transform: rotate(-90deg)` to that list *at the bottom*.

Comment: Thanks a bunch..you made my day...works like a charm

Comment: @Ezhil You should accept [Mohammed's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32609308/1150683). Instead of relying on CSS, you can do this in angular from the start!

Answer (score 0):

Remove class attribute from the div and implement via ng-class just like if else statement.

```
 <th class="scenarioTableHeader alignVerticalText" ng-repeat="column in cols">
         <div ng-class="{'scenarioBranchHeader':$first,'verticalTextScenario':!$first}">
    {{column}}
     </div>
</th>
```